# save data like session and cache in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, session, caching

as you all know we simply use

```
Session["kurd"]="";
```

or

`Cahce.Insert(...)`

and its save data in memory;
its save data without serialize or any thing like that so we can simply save everything

but its not reliable way to save data;

> so may you guys say you can save on database or file but in my case
>   it  cant be done, because my data its not serializable,  and i can
>   only save it in **cache** , **session** , **viewdata**,**viewbage**
>   ,... because it dos not need to be serialize data first ; and because
>   of not reliability in session , cache ,... i want way that can save
>   data just like cache and session ,... without serialize data

anyone knows how we can do such thing (save data) in disk
i mean save data on hard drive just like session did on memory?

**update :**

the data type is instance of that class in picture that contain httpclient , httpclienthandeler,deviceinfo,...

[image]

**update :**

how wonderful it is that no one knows 
how can i save data in hard drive just like what session did in memory
no question no serialize no bs, just save it very easy

Comment: Save in text file or so?

Comment: When you say it's not serializeable, what data are you trying to store? Can you post examples?

Comment: @wheels73 tanks for your answer i update it

Comment: @user3250 I want to save it in hard drive in any way or save in ram (for long time like 20 days)

Comment: @ShoppingCenterCNC - have a look at this answer. This uses Json serialization by creating custom class to wrap httpClient etc.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335897/using-json-net-to-serialize-object-into-httpclients-response-stream

Comment: @wheels73 tanks but that link is totally different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem
HttpClient cant be serialize but 
i found out that the only thing in HttpClient that we should save in this thread
is "CookieContainer"
so serlize and deserilze like this

```
var formatter = new SoapFormatter();
string file = "..\cookies.dat"; 
//
using (Stream s = File.Create (file))
    formatter.Serialize(s, cookies);                            
//
CookieContainer retrievedCookies = null;
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead (file))
    retrievedCookies = (CookieContainer) formatter.Deserialize(s);
```

so i serialize it and save it and then for new use i create new HttpClient and assign that **CookieContainer** to **HttpClent.CookieContainer**

this problem was for **Instasharper**

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically you can use [ObjectDumper](https://github.com/lassevk/ObjectDumper).

Or, if you are debugging, you can use a Visual Studio extension called [Object Exporter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter)